# How to create a "loading" spinner in Breeze?

Tags: breeze

I'm trying to create a loading spinner that will be displayed when breeze is communicating with the server. Is there some property in Breeze that is 'true' only when breeze is sending data to the server, receiving data, or waiting for a response (e.g. after an async call has been made but no response yet)?  I thought of binding this data to a knockout observable and binding the spinner to this observable,

Thanks,

Elior

Answer (score 1):

Use spin.js

http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/

Its so simple..make it visible before you execute the query and disable it after the query succeeds or fails.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any property that is set or observable while Breeze is querying, but if you are using a datacontext, or some JavaScript module for your data calls, this is what you can do -

**EDIT**

Taking John's comments into account, I added a token'd way of tracking each query.

```
    var activeQueries = ko.observableArray();

    var isQuerying = ko.computed(function () {
        return activeQueries().length !== 0;
    });

    var toggleQuery = function (token) {
        if (activeQueries.indexOf(token) === -1)
        { activeQueries.push(token); }
        else { activeQueries.remove(token); }
    };

    var getProducts = function (productsObservable, forceRemote) {
        // Don't toggle if you aren't getting it remotely since this is synchronous
        if (!forceRemote) {
            var p = getLocal('Products', 'Product','product_id'); 
            if (p.length > 0) {
                productsObservable(p);
                return Q.resolve(); 
            }
        }

        // Create a token and toggle it
        var token = 'products' + new Date().getTime();
        toggleQuery(token);

        var query = breeze.EntityQuery
            .from("Products");

        return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            var s = data.results;
            log('Retrieved [Products] from remote data source', s, true);
            // Toggle it off
            toggleQuery(token);
            return productsObservable(s);
        }
    };
```

You will need to make sure all of your fail logic toggles the query as well.

Then in your view where you want to place the spinner

```
var spinnerState = ko.computed(function () {
    datacontext.isQuerying();
};
```

Comment: That will work if you query 1 at a time, but once you start running multiple, the flag needs to know about all the active queries. I am not sure there is value in showing a spinner for every query to the server tho. Instead, I show a spinner and disable elements for user stories. For example, the user goes to a new screen and the spinner appears til the screen is ready. There are several actions that causes this to wait, in a unit of work, if you will.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the detailed example and explanation.  This is what I thought of doing too.  While reading your example I was thinking - is it possible to overload 'manager.executeQuery' so as to add this functionality to it?  or perhaps add a prototype function (manager.prototype.executeQuery or something like that) to be used instead of the 'real' exectureQuery, and another prototype variable to manager that will be set to true before calling the 'real' manager.executeQuery and false afterwards.  What do you think about this possibility?  Thanks again !  Elior

Comment: One issue I could see with adding a prototype or an additional layer of the query is that without studying ever case in depth you may trigger the querying property and may not always 'stop' it.  This could happen to my amended solution as well but at least you have more control.  I edited the answer to include a token for each query to track multiple queries.  LMK if this helps.

Comment: Thanks John and Kadumel, I'll explore these options further and report here for the results in the comming days.  Thank you both !

Comment: Hi again John and Kadumel.  Thank you both, your support is valuable for me, but I have decided currently to handle the situation "per call" and not generally.  If I'll return back to the issue, I'll report here on the solution.  Elior